# Acquire JSON data into html using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this php/json file that i call `users-json.php`.

```
<?php
include_once('../functions.php');
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
$GetID = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT Username, Firstname  WHERE UserID = :ID";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':ID' => $GetID));
} else {
$query = "SELECT Username, Firstname FROM users";   
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
}
$userData = array();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $userData[] = $row;
}
//udskriv bruger data som JSON
echo json_encode($userData);
?>
```

Json output:

```
[{"Username":"Admin","Firstname":""},{"Username":"Bruger","Firstname":"Ole"}]
```

I Want it to display the data in a list like this, by using jquery.

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | username | firstname | lastname |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I have tried this on my own so far but it does not seem to work.

Comment: it's too broad... what are you trying to achieve.. the modal or the list ?

Comment: I think i would need the list function to work in order to better understand how it all works.

i tried reading this:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp 
- but to start with I think i would need the list function to work for the php code i got this echo something like this
[code]
[{"Username":"Admin","Firstname":""},{"Username":"User","Firstname":"Ole"}]
[/code]

Comment: do you mean "list" is like table format ?

Comment: yeah like a table format..... so i better can understand json, and how to work with the arrays etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use with php and javascript

**Javascript/JQuery**

After you got your `$userData`, You need to use `$.parseJSON();` to parse the json into object, you have to use `JQuery`. Because your JSON are in php variable, you need to change that into javascript variable.

```
<?php
 $userdata = '[{"Username":"Admin","Firstname":""},{"Username":"Bruger","Firstname":"Ole"}]' 
?>
```

And your javascript would be like this, note that, you have to use JQuery Libaray to make this thing works

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = '<?php echo $userdata ?>';
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        var html= "";

     for(i=0,no=1;i<Object.keys(json).length;i++){
     html+='<tr><td>'+json[i].Username+'</td><td>'+json[i].Firstname+'</td></tr>';
     }
    $('#data').html(html);
    </script>
```

And your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
   table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Username
    </td>
    <td>
    FIrstname
    </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">  
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Summary**

```
<?php
     $userdata = '[{"Username":"Admin","Firstname":""},{"Username":"Bruger","Firstname":"Ole"}]'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
       table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      </style>
<table border>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Username
    </td>
    <td>
    FIrstname
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="data">  
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = '<?php echo $userdata ?>';
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        var html= "";

     for(i=0,no=1;i<Object.keys(json).length;i++){
     html+='<tr><td>'+json[i].Username+'</td><td>'+json[i].Firstname+'</td></tr>';
     }
    $('#data').html(html);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: so how from the to show it like i wanted'?
<pre>
[id] [username] [firstname][lastname]
[id] [username] [firstname][lastname]
[id] [username] [firstname][lastname]</pre>

Comment: i want the function in javscript so it displays a html list / table

Comment: i have added the summary

Answer (score 0):

This made it work for me thanks for your answer it gave me so many anwsers

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.getJSON("http://localhost/NewSite/php-pages/User-json.php", function(data) {
         var json = data;
         for(i=0,no=1;i<Object.keys(json).length;i++){
         $('UserTable').append('<tr><td>'+json[i].Username+'</td><td>'+json[i].Firstname+'</td></tr>');
         }
         });
     });
    </script>

    <body>
    <table id="UserTable"></table>
    </body>
```